# Install Options on Python Setup.py Files

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I have a python package that I create a package using setuptools.

It creates an .egg file and loads it into the site-package folder for my python win 32-bit library.

My question is this.  If there a way to create the setup.py so it can move the files to the site-package lib folder not creating an egg or are eggs the new thing at setuptools 3.3?

I am running into errors with my code on various machines, and I want to be able to step through to the code, but the egg will not allow me to do this.

Thank you

Comment: The reason I do not want to use an egg file is because I cannot debug my python code, but I need something to distribute the code to the site package location on my test boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I just did the following in the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(...)
```

I had list my individual packages in the packages option on the setup function.

It created both the .egg file and the package in the site=packages folder.